# How to use Show with Rotate

Tags: graphics

The following use of `Show` produces an error (*Could not combine the graphics objects in Show*) even though the two graphics objects are constructed just fine.

```
g1 = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}]
g2 = Rotate[g1, \[Pi]]
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

Can `Show` somehow be used to combine graphics objects, where some are rotated?

Note: even `Show[{g2}]` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or take the graphic details with First, Rotate them, then plot again with Graphic:

```
    g1 = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}]
    g2 = Graphics[Rotate[First@g1, \[Pi]]]
    Show[{g1, g2}]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives a more accurate layout than `Overlay`.

Answer (score 2):

`g2` has head `Rotate`, so use `Overlay`

```
Overlay[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For 3D figure, if the function Overlay is used, the obtained figure is two dimensional. It cann't be rotated using the mouse. To solve this problem, we can take other methodes.
Giving an example

```
myBox = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}]];

myBox = Graphics3D[Rotate[myBox[[1]], Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]]
```

Then, you can use the Show[]. It is very simple. You can do like this to apply to other situations.

Comment: This is what accepted answer uses, is it not?

Comment: Aming at the above answer, just for a clearer explanation of the problems of the Overlay and a clear answer to the 3D figure.

Comment: I keep reading [MyBox](https://www.mybox.eu) in this thread and it keeps appearing in the SERPs for Self Storage searches. Any Chance we can remove this keyword from this thread or make this page noindex?